# Do I need to repeat the "are" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, ellipses

Example 1: Recent interdisciplinary studies advance the argument that emotions are social phenomena but not separable from bodily response.

Example 2: Recent interdisciplinary studies advance the argument that emotions are social phenomena but **are** not separable from bodily response.

Do I have to have the "are" to make this sentence correct? It sounds wrong to me to not have it, but I know I technically don't have to repeat the verb, right? For example, I can say: I am happy but tired. I don't need to say: I am happy but I am tired.

Comment: I would go for your second example.

Comment: 'How it sounds' is a nebulous concept; it takes decades to think you've got even close to having a decent ear. But I agree with @Centaurus that deleting the second 'are' (your first example) sounds less natural.

Comment: Either is fine, but it seems to me you could delete *but not* in Example 1 and *but are* in Example 2 without changing the meaning of either sentence.

Comment: Both examples are grammatically correct, but the second sounds better. Unlike @RichardKayser, I'd leave "but" in the sentence (in both versions) to make it clear that "not separable from bodily response" is something  unexpected for social phenomena (and in fact seems to mean that they aren't entirely social).

Comment: @AndreasBlass I did consider that regarding the *but*, but :-) on second thought, I think you’re right. Given that, I also prefer *but are*.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Final takeaway: both are grammatically correct, but the second does "sound better", probably due to the length of the sentence.